# Django blocktrans error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-errors

I am nearing the final stages of a project and have run into a bit of a hiccup with Django.

It relates to the `{% blocktrans %}` tag.

How do I enable it to be fully functional in my app, currently if I wrap a piece of text in `{% blocktrans %}` I get a `TemplateSyntaxError` message

I have the following in my

`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (

    ...

    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",

    ...

)`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whats the actual error message ?? Actual sample code will be helpful. {%blocktrans%}text{%endblocktrans%} TemplateSyntaxError is very rare.

Comment: Hi.

I am using django-notification
it is the following.

> {% load i18n %}{% blocktrans %}{{ notice }}{% endblocktrans %}

> TemplateSyntaxError - Caught an exception while rendering: notice

Answer (score 3):

For me was like this (windows + python 2.6 + django 1.2.1)

1. Will result an error(TemplateSyntaxError):

   {% load i18n %}

   {% blocktrans %} My name is {{ user.firstname }} {% endblocktrans %}
2. Will work:

   {% load i18n %}

   {% blocktrans with user.firstname as hmpf %} My name is {{ hmpf }} {% endblocktrans %}